# find the maximum of the function $f(x)=a+b\sqrt{2}\sin{x}+c\sin{2x}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

let $a,b,c\in R$,and such $a^2+b^2+c^2=100$, find the maximum value and minimum value of the function
$$f(x)=a+b\sqrt{2}\sin{x}+c\sin{2x},0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:**
$$\left(a+b\sqrt{2}\sin{x}+c\sin{2x}\right)^2\le (a^2+b^2+c^2)(1+2\sin^2x+\sin^22x)$$
$$\left(a+b\sqrt{2}\sin{x}+c\sin{2x}\right)^2\le 100\cdot(1+2\sin^2x+\sin^22x)$$
$$|a+b\sqrt{2}\sin{x}+c\sin{2x}|\le 10\cdot\sqrt{1+2\sin^2x+\sin^22x}$$
$$1\le1+2\sin^2x+\sin^22x\le \frac{13}{4}$$
Then $$-5\sqrt{13}\le a+b\sqrt{2}\sin{x}+c\sin{2x}\le 5\sqrt{13}$$